# Unable to delete Column

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, lookup-column, column, delete

Forgive me if this has been asked before but I have not been able to find a solution that works. I am currently teaching myself how to use SharePoint.

I have created some columns that have errors in the formula in them and I can't delete or edit the formula (I have them hidden at the minute and that isn't a problem).

Also I have a column that I tried to use a look up in and made it a required field I now can't edit it to remove the 'required' restriction.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to delete or edit the column details follow below steps :-

1. Go to the List or Library.
2. Select Settings button from SharePoint Online [image]

3. Click on the **List Settings** option which will open a settings page for that particular list.
4. Then click on the column that you want to edit the formula of/delete it .
5. At the bottom, you can see a **Delete** button . Click on it to delete the column .

Comment: Thanks really simple thing that i hadn't realised i could do

Comment: You're welcome GraemeM.